# request email notification on question

Tags: support

How do I request email notification on a question that I did not post whenever a new answer is posted on stackexchange sites?

Comment: Good question - however, since the question is about the platform and not specifically about the money.* site, you're better off asking it at http://meta.stackoverflow.com, the meta site for all Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is a supported feature of stackexchange sites.  You've got two reasonable ways to track questions.

1. Mark the question as a favorite (click the star near the voting buttons).   When you log back in, you'll see a banner telling you that you have a "favorite" change.
2. At the bottom of every question page is a little rss symbol and the phrase "question feed".   Subscribe via rss to the questions you are interested in.  You may even be able to find an Rss->email tool somewhere so that you can get them via email.

Comment: Great answer!   I always forget about the question RSS feature.